# how to embed two images in same textbox or rectangle

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display image according to my db result in SSRS.My DB result Is

```
ID  Name    indicator
--  -----   ------------
1   xxx       1 
2   yyy       0
3   zzz       0
```

If sum of indicator is 1 i need o display one image if sum of indicator is 0 i need to display another image.Please let me know how to display this images in SSRS.Images need to be placed in same textbox or rectangle.Please help.

Comment: Is this a single image or per row? If single image what if `SUM(indicator)` is more than 1?

Comment: single image only.Indicator will be 1 or 0 not more than 1.If it is 1 i want image 1 else image 2.Also how to add two image in same cell.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the Image Value property using an expression, along the lines of:

`= Iif ( Sum ( Fields!indicator.Value ) = 1 , "Image1", "Image0" )`